# Determinants/Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Consider the matrices $A_1, A_2$ and $A_3$ below. For each i = 1, 2, 3, let $S_i$ be the set of all vectors $(a, b, c, d) \in \mathbb R^4$ such that $A_i$ is singular. Find out which of the sets $S_i$ are subspaces of $\mathbb R^4$. In each case when $S_i$ is a subspace, find a basis in it.
[image]

Comment: Use Gaussian elimination in A1 and A3 to show the $S_i$ are vector subspaces. In A2 you found a non-linear equation defining $S_2,$ can that be a _linear_ subspace?

Comment: @WillM. yh, I was quite tired when I was solving it... So missed the fact that non-linear equation means that it just can't be a subspace of R4. But I am still stuck. My det(A1)=-43a + 36b - 12c - 20d = 0 and det(A3) = 0a + 0b + 0c + 0d = 0. I am not sure how to apply gaussian elimination to these to show that they are vector subspaces. and how find our sets Si in general..

Comment: The kernel of a linear function is always a subspace of the domain. Are you still tired?